# How to make background of SurfaceView Transparent?

Tags: android, background, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView named MyBringBackSurface, and the constructor is:

```
public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    }
```

The background shows up but how to make it transparent so it show other Bitmaps in front of it?

Comment: surfaceview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

use Color.TRANSPARENT as a background color for your surfaceview.

If you want to show bitmap over the surface view  you can try something like below xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraSurface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/IV_MASK"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/mask"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried It 
I wrote : setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); right ?
the backround has gone @AAnkit

Comment: that is what you mentioned in the question, To make surface view as transparent. Please make your question clear?